# How can I create a "Restore Previous Session" button on my custom HTML Homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, xul, xpcom

**about:home** in Mozilla Firefox opens an HTML page, that has a "Restore Previous Session" button.
Upon clicking that button a previous session is restored.
I am creating my custom HTML homepage and want to put there such a button.
**How can I achieve that?**
I found this code, but it does not work in HTML, I suspect it works only in XUL.

```
function RestoreSession(){
  var Cc = Components.classes;
  var Ci = Components.interfaces;
  var ss = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/sessionstore;1"].getService(Ci.nsISessionStore);
  if (ss.canRestoreLastSession) {ss.restoreLastSession();}
};
```

Also there is a JavaScript code module "**AboutHome.jsm**" but I do not know if I can use it from an HTML page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that you cannot do this with an external page, and that this is only possible using the pages that are native to the browsers.  I belibe that this is built into the code.  I may be wrong, but quite certain, so please correct me if I am.

Comment: Hi, Maxcr1! You may be right. I wonder how they did it work in the about:home page. When I save the about:home page as HTML, and then open it from the file, the "Restore Previous Session" button does not work. I wish there were a workaround.

Comment: I am really sorry that I was not able to help.

Comment: That's Ok. It is still nice talking with you.